# RPart on PCA and centering data

Tags: r

I am using the results of PCA in a classification model.  All is well, but I am observing one artifact that has me puzzled.

Basically, when running the PCA model using prcomp(), if I set the "center=T" parameter, my classification accuracy suffers (0.83).  If I set "center=F", then my classification accuracy improves (0.90).

My question is: why?  I cannot think of any specific reason why centering data during prcomp() will cause subsequent prediction using it to suffer?

The code is below.  Any help in understanding this behavior will be much appreciated.  Thanks a lot in advance!

```
library(rpart)
library(caret)
library(rpart.plot)

data(iris)
index <- sample(1:nrow(iris), size=0.2*nrow(iris))
test <- iris[index, ]
train <- iris[-index, ]

# Build the model on raw data for a sanity check.
model <- rpart(Species~Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width, method="class", data=train)    
pred <- predict(model, test[, 1:4], type="class")

# The confusion matrix below shows an accuracy of 0.90.
confusionMatrix(pred, test[, 5])

# Now do the PCA part for classification
pca <- prcomp(train[, 1:4], scale.=T, center=T) # <---- NOTE if we change this to F, we get better performance

# "Fit" the test data into Z-space based on the loadings (or rotations) from the training.
test.zspace <- predict(pca, newdata=test[, 1:4])
pca.train.df <- as.data.frame(pca$x)
pca.train.df$Species <- train[, 5]

# Build the model on the PCs.
pca.model <- rpart(Species ~ ., method="class", data=pca.train.df)

pca.test.df <- as.data.frame(test.zspace)
pca.test.df$Species <- test[, 5]
pca.pred <- predict(pca.model, pca.test.df[, 1:4], type="class")

# Confusion matrix below shows an accuracy of 0.83.  If I do NOT center the data during prcomp(), it will show 0.90.
confusionMatrix(pca.pred, test[, 5])
```

Comment: There could be several reasons. One is that if you have coding where 0 (and in some cases other values) is meaningful in the raw data, then centering the data could reduce information provided by the data. Another may be the tiny sample size of the iris data causing a spurious result, or over-fitting since the validation methodology is overly simplistic. Incidentally if you mean artifact in the sense of a tangible byproduct of the code being developed, I'm not sure that the term is being used correctly.

Comment: It is a good practice to apply scale & center parameter so that variables are standardized prior to performing PCA. Non-normalized variables may influence principal components and center=T is the option to standardize features before the application of PCA.

Comment: @Hack-R I didn't understand why centering the data could reduce information provided by the data.

Comment: Hack-R and F. Prive: thanks!

Comment: Prem, thanks; as a general rule of caution, what you say is true.  But  note that in the Iris dataset, the attribute values are relatively close; their variance is low.  Hence I was playing around looking at the effect of center and scale parameters on the result.

Answer (score 0):

It is important that when you compare some results, you have an estimation of the variance of these two results in order to know if one is statistically significantly better than the other.
For example, if you perfom some bootstrap, you can see that these two results are not significantly different:

```
rep1 <- replicate(1e4, {
  ind <- sample(length(pred), replace = TRUE)
  mean(pca.pred[ind] == test[ind, 5])
})

rep2 <- replicate(1e4, {
  ind <- sample(length(pred), replace = TRUE)
  mean(pred[ind] == test[ind, 5]) 
})

boxplot(cbind(rep1, rep2))
```

[image: Boxplot results of the bootstrap]

I think it is always a good idea to use centering AND scaling of your matrix before using PCA. You can find why in the first part of my [blog post](https://privefl.github.io/blog/(Linear-Algebra)-Do-not-scale-your-matrix/#why-scaling-matrices).

Comment: Hmmm...thanks, that makes sense; a nice think to keep in mind.

Comment: @VictorSemanic If you are happy with the answer, please validate it.